# PHPSpreadsheet - Spreadsheet.php failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: php, laravel, phpspreadsheet

I am developing a Laravel web application that uses the library PHPSpreadsheet. It creates a new workbook and then generates a graph inside the workbook. This is my code.

```
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;  

class MakeCertificates 
{
    public static function createReport($id)
    {
        // Setup
        //intiate workbook
        $spreadsheet = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet();
    ...
```

My code works on localhost xampp however I have deployed it to a web server and receive the following error.

```
include(/home/machgr5/sis.machgroup.co.uk/vendor/composer/../phpoffice/phpspreadsheet/src/PhpSpreadsheet/Spreadsheet.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

I get this error at this line:

```
$spreadsheet = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet();
```

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Did you install your dependencies on that machine? Something like `php composer.phar install`?

Answer (score 0):

This can happen for a few reasons. The things I can immediatly tell:

This is correct

```
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
```

But instantiate without the full namespace in your method:

```
$spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
```

Next the autoloader is telling you he can't find the location of your PHPSpreadsheet class. Did you install it on your server? (Run `composer install`)

Maybe run `composer dumpautoload -o` as well, which will rebuild the class map for you.